# Trouble connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to 2 databases. One of them is a remote database. Once i connected to the remote database i had trouble with the one that existed, it gave me 'supplied argument is not valid ' on `mysql_fetch_array()` . So i changed my database class a bit and tried to make it work. But i still get errors :(. Its not grabbing `$connection` variable.
i get "undefined variable connection".
this is my connection class. Please help me out. Appreciate your help.

```
global $connection;

class Database{

function __construct()
{
    $this->open_connection();
}

public function open_connection()
{

    $connection = $this->connection= mysql_connect(SERVER,UNAME,PASSWORD);

    if(!$this->connection)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$this->connection))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public function close_connection()
{
    mysql_close($this->connection);
}
 //open_connection();
 }

$database = new Database();
```

and in another page:

```
$result=mysql_query($query,$connection);        

while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result)) ... etc
```

p.s all constants and other variables are correct.

Comment: are you getting any error ? if yes post it..

Comment: where those constants are defined?

Comment: are you overwriting the $connection once you open the second databased connection, since it is a global?

Comment: Replace all occurrence of `$this->connection with $connection`, `$this->connection means you should have a class variable name $connection then you can access $this->connection`

Answer (score 1):

Using a global variable in a class is like death.
You could provide a class field for the connection link

```
$this->connection = mysql_connect(...);
```

And outside your class

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $object->connection);
```

I'd also suggest you to use the existing mysqli class.

Comment: thanks , where can i find mysqli  class? i haven't heard of it.

Comment: ok this is what i tried next, i declared `public $connection;` inside the class and put `$this->connection= mysql_connect(SERVER,UNAME,PASSWORD);` inside open_connection(). then , `$con=$database->connection;` and now it give me "Undefined variable: database" :((

Comment: You forgot to change the connection handler in the mysql_select_db execution? mysqli is a standard extension, you dont have to install it manually, all information can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: If you want to switch to mysqli here's a little example for your multi-db thing. $db1 = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname'); $db2 = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname'); Or put them in 1 Array

Comment: thanks a lot. ill look into it. but i like to find why my original code is not working too. it's `mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$this->connection)`.  and after the database class i make an instant of it that is `$database`. that whole thing is in one page. i include it into next page where i query the database. why is it undefined??? :o

Comment: i edit it again now i made a new instance of Database class after including it. in the next page `$database1 = new Database();
    $con=$database1->connection;` and now i works ! how can that happen?

Comment: You should always put classes in external files, I can't explain why it's working now and not before without seeing your code situation but yea congratz for your success :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Well, it looks like you are getting an undefined error thrown because you are calling global $connection at the top of the class file, and it hasn't been assigned a value.

It looks like you are establishing $connection inside of the open_connection() method... Are you establishing $connection in some included file that you haven't mentioned?

Try removing the first line of code, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

the "global $connection;" MUST be inside "open_connection" method or use @peipst9lker method